# how to prevent internet explorer from caching ajax request in angular2, typescript?

Tags: ajax, http, angular, caching, typescript

Scenario is that user have some points lets say 10 pts. so after clicking on button an ajax get call sent to server that update the points of user as he/she consumed it. So, server should send 9 which is working on all browsers except Internet Explorer. After searching I found that IE not even making the request it is caching that request. How to solve this issue ?

Thanx in advance !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have control on the server code, you should set the appropriate headers that disallow caching.

You can set the headers

```
Cache-Control: no-cache
Expires: -1
```

Answer (score 1):

A possible approach would be to implement an HTTP interceptor and append a timestamp if the request with the URL has already been executed.

```
@Injectable()
export class CustomHttp extends Http {
  urls: {string:string} = {};

  get(url: string, options?: RequestOptionsArgs): Observable<Response> {
    if (this.urls[url]) {
      options = options || {};
      options.search = options.search || new URLSearchParams();
      options.search.set('timestamp', (new Date()).getTime());
    }

    return super.get(url, options).do(() => {
      this.urls[url] = true;
    });
  }
}
```